# How to link Visual Studio Code to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having an issue getting this to work. Please be kind i'm really new to VSCode and its interface is a little hard to get around in...

I've installed the VSTS Extension but i'm unable to do the Git Repo Cloning and not sure if anyone has found any better resources for getting this to work... ANy help would be grateful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even without the vsts extension installed you can make use of vscode and git.

Open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (this wil open a powershell intergrated terminal)

Enter the command: `git clone [url of repo]`

A popup will appear to enter your VSTS credentials, afterwards the repo will start cloning.

Open the cloned folder and VSCode will show the current branch in the bottom left corner of the screen.

Comment: If you want to make use of the VSTS Extension, open the repo folder press ctrl shift p and type in Team: signin. Or select the Team: in the lower corner of the screen and follow the signin instructions